# Microsoft Teams meetings via Graph API authorization issue: 403 Forbidden

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have faced a problem with authorization and inability to use Graph API for Online Meetings creation.

We've successfully passed following steps:

1. created an account in Azure (using gmail)
2. registered our application with all necessary rights for Online Meeting creation;
3. created a tenant (Azure Free AD) and a couple of users within it;
4. assigned these users to the application and got all necessary rights for them via admin consent;

After this we were able to get an auth token for these users using 'password' grant type flow (OnlineMeetings should be requested only on behalf of the real user, Application type is not supported for them). This token is valid: it has all necessary scopes inside and we are able to call /me or /users Graph API endpoints.

**But when we are trying to call POST /me/onlineMeetings in order to create a meeting we are getting 403 Forbidden.**
The sample response is the following:

```js
{
  "error": {
  "code": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Forbidden",
  "innerError": {
   "date": "2020-09-10T09:11:41",
   "request-id": "33207d63-44db-4e7e-97fb-e60dcad1928d"
   }
  }
}
```

Could you please help us what is wrong with that?

Comment: Could you please share the url & request body? Also could you please check the all the permissions required to create a online meeting by pasting the auth token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)?

Answer (score 0):

Timur - please check the documentation again. There have been updates as recently as Sep 22. The below article should work for you (create event). OnlineMeetings one still seems to have issues..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Please write the change in the answer, link may break in the future, rendering useless your answer